# oauthCard login opens empty window

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, azure-authentication

I have the following code:

```
import { ActivityTypes, CardFactory, TurnContext } from "botbuilder";

export class MyBot {
    /**
     * Handles incoming activity, received from a user, processes it, and replies as needed
     * @param {TurnContext} context on turn context object.
     */
    public onTurn = async (turnContext: TurnContext) => {
        const oauthCard = CardFactory.oauthCard("ms-graph", "Login", "Please sign in so I know who you are");
        return await turnContext.sendActivity({ attachments: [oauthCard] });
    }
}
```

When I run the bot in bot emulator framework, I see the login button. When I click on it however, it just opens an empty signin window that's all white.

I've also configured authentication in Azure:

[image]

Edit: I've also configured the app id and password in my `.bot` file.

Comment: Is ngrok configured for the emulator?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#use-the-emulator-to-test-your-bot

Comment: Interesting. It's not. But the company I works for blocks it for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to use Azure Service Bus in place of ngrok which may work for you. It functions much the same but gives you control over where your data is traveling when "tunneling", among other benefits. As it's an Azure service, it can live in the same subscription you already access.

In short, you'll create a local client application that connects your bot via a relay to the Azure Service Bus service. The service bus namespace/relay replaces the messaging endpoint in the bot settings in Azure (for testing). In this way your bot running on localhost can connect to external services. Just be sure to use the same endpoint in Emulator that you use in the Azure bot settings, including the "/api/messages".

The instructions found [here](https://github.com/stevkan/blogs/blob/master/Using%20Azure%20Service%20Bus%20With%20Your%20Bot/Using%20Azure%20Service%20Bus%20With%20Your%20Bot.md) can guide you thru the process of setting up and running. The steps are a little long looking but the process itself is fairly simple. There are two options to build: a .NET Framework and a .NET Core. I would recommend the "Framework" version unless you need to run this on a Mac. This isn't an official MS blog (yet) but expect it to show up there.

Hope of help!